# setting up named routes for resouce routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have what I think should be a simple task - but it's causing me a real headache.

I've added a resource route to my app using -

```
resources :cars
```

I want the user to be able to edit a car by going to

```
mydomain.com/CARNAME
```

In the edit action of the controller -

```
@donor = Donor.find_by_name(params[:car])
```

This page shows by setting up a named route -

```
match "/:car" =>"cars#edit", :as => :car
```

However when I try and submit the form on that page I get an error?

How can I set up the show action to have a named route to correspond with the edit route?

My desired show url would be something like

```
mydomain.com/CARNAME/savecomplete
```

Comment: if you are not using the RESTfull routes, why are you using resource in your routes?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand restful routes properly? I assumed that changing a name of a route didn't effect restful principles. Am I wrong? If so, can you point me towards an article that would teach me otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In routes.rb

```
match "/:car" =>"cars#edit", :as => :edit_car
match "/:car/savecomplete" =>"cars#show", :as => :savecomplete
```

In cars_controller.rb update action

```
format.html { redirect_to(savecomplete_path(@car) }
```